# Meu site foi clonado?

Tags: php

Alguns meses atrás estive criando um projeto em php, uma espécie de loja virtual, nada muito complexo.

Um certo dia me deparei com um site relativamente parecido com o meu, ai me veio a pergunta: Pode ser um clone do meu site?

Após alguns dias de pesquisa, não achei um método de como descobrir a verdade. Queria a ajuda de vocês,pois sou novato em programação, comprei um curso online e com base nos conhecimentos aprendido criei a loja.

Era um curso do Neri... queria saber como posso descobrir ou confirmar que o site meu foi clonado. Posso processar legalmente o Admin do site?

Agradeço a sinceridade de vocês, não pretendo tomar medidas nesse caso, até porque fiz algo apenas para conhecimento, mas futuramente quando fazer um site decente preciso ter uma ideia de como agir nessas horas.

Agradeço a ajuda antecipadamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pergunta é um bocado subjetiva, mas pelo meu conhecimento, podes sim "clonar" pelo menos o aspeto do site alterando algumas coisas, até porque tens acesso ao `css`, ao `javascript` e ao `html` da página, depois é só fazer o `php` ou seja o que for para que a página funcione. Quanto a legalidade disso não te sei responder. Seria melhor falar com um advogado perito no assunto, até porque no que diz respeito as leis relativamente a informática ainda está muito por fazer, pelo menos em Portugal.

Comment: vou esperar mais respostas, mas obrigado pela sua colaboração!

Answer (score 0):

Embora a pergunta não seja sobre desenvolvimento, e difícil de responder na ausência de mais detalhes, vou tentar dar uma resposta. Em primeiro lugar, se você criou a loja "com base nos conhecimentos advindos de um curso online", eu pergunto: o quão diferente é seu site daquilo que é descrito no curso? Seria possível que o autor do suposto clone não estivesse simplesmente seguindo o mesmo curso?

Dependendo das tecnologias envolvidas, é muito provável que dois sites com o mesmo propósito acabem parecidos. Por exemplo, dois blogs que usam o wordpress e usem um tema comum vão sair parecidos. Dois sites que usem o mesmo sistema de CMS vão sair parecidos. Etc. Dizer que seu site foi clonado apenas baseado na similaridade é temerário, você precisa de evidências mais concretas.

Por fim, é bom lembrar que tudo o que fica exposto ao cliente (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, imagens, etc) pode ser copiado - legal ou ilegalmente. Se vale a pena ou não acionar legalmente quem copiou, aí e uma decisão sua. Consulte um advogado para mais detalhes. Pessoalmente, não me preocuparia com isso - a menos que fosse uma cópia descarada envolvendo uma quantidade imensa de código que fosse de minha própria autoria (e não código herdado, seja de projetos open source ou de materiais de referência). [Resposta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7271/215).