# Técnicas e dicas de compressão javascript

Tags: javascript

Recentemente achei por caso uma outra forma de usar o *true* e o *false* substituindo eles por *!0* e *!1*. Fiquei pensando em outras formas de comprimir os códigos ou deixá-los mais "secretos" porem não achei nada na internet falando ao respeito, somente dando links para compressores de javascript.

Tentei até dá uma olhada em livrarias JS, mas já sabe, não da entender nada, então queria saber quais 'técnicas' ou dicas que vocês usam para diminuir o tamanho dos códigos.

Comment: A minha sugestão é mesmo usar uma biblioteca que faça isso. Fazer à mão é arriscado, pode dar erros. Há muitos detalhes a ter em conta como `true === 1 // false`.

Comment: Se pra você o fato de `!0` resultar em `false` é algo secreto, você precisa rever os seus conceitos.

Comment: nem todo mundo sabe disso @Renan ..

Answer (score 7):

Não "compile seu código à mão"! Lembre-se que "programas devem ser escritos para as pessoas lerem, e só por acaso para máquinas executarem."

A razão pela qual as pessoas usam minificadores (ou ofuscadores) de JavaScript é justamente porque esse trabalho manual é desnecessário, repetitivo e sujeito a erros:

- Seu código fica mais difícil de ler;
- Seu código fica mais difícil de depurar (ao ver uma mensagem de erro, é mais difícil localizá-lo nos fontes);
- Erros simples (tal como [exemplificado por Sergio nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21132/t%C3%A9cnicas-e-dicas-de-compress%C3%A3o-javascript#comment38224_21132)), que seriam imediatamente visíveis num código "limpo" poderiam passar despercebidos num código que use muitos truques desse tipo.
- Muitas vezes o processo de minimizar o código é "burro" (ex.: trocar todas as variáveis de muitas letras por variáveis de uma letra só), de modo que é melhor delegar essa tarefa para uma ferramenta do que fazê-la você mesmo.

  - E, complementando, essa ferramenta poderá fazer coisas que você não pensaria em fazer no código fonte original (ex.: remover todas as quebras de linha e identações).
- E, no final das contas, a maioria dos webservers **comprime** os conteúdos (usando gzip ou deflate) antes de enviar aos clientes, de modo que mesmo os ganhos com a minificação não *me parecem* ser tão grandes quando se supõe (opinião; não tenho fatos concretos para servir de base).

Por essas razões, não é recomendado fazer esse tipo de alteração diretamente nos códigos-fontes se sua única razão é diminuir o tamanho. Mantenha seu código claro e limpo, e deixe que outros programas o "enfeie" para você.

P.S. Você também menciona 'deixá-los mais "secretos"', o que eu entendi como uma tentativa de "proteger o código-fonte", certo? Se for isso, sugiro que leia [essa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7271/215) a uma pergunta relacionada. Muitas pessoas usam ofuscadores não com seu propósito original de ofuscar, mas sim por terem melhor performance no sentido de percentual de redução do tamanho do código.

Comment: Entendi o que quer dizer, sempre usei essas técnicas de 'ofuscamento' e nunca tive problemas ao achar bugs ou algum erro, não levo isso ao máximo (como deixar todo o código em somente uma linha) mas gosto de usar novas técnicas e dificultar o entendimento para outras pessoas ou simplesmente para enfeitá-lo mesmo. Mas realmente, acabei concordando com a sua resposta.