# Software para ofuscar APK

Tags: java, android

Não sei essa questão é valida levantar aqui de acordo com as politicas de perguntas mas caso não seja eu a removerei, uma breve pesquisa na internet achei varias ferramentas inclusive sites que fazem a descompilação de um apk

[decompileandroid](http://www.decompileandroid.com/)

[android-apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

[AndroChef](http://www.neshkov.com/ac_decompiler.html)

De uma certa form isso nos deixa muito frustados na ideia de criar um produto mas não conseguir proteger nossa propriedade intelectual.

fiz uma pesquisa sobre alguns software para o ofuscamento do apk mas ainda continuo em duvidas de quais medidas tomar para proteger meu produto, qual melhor software\solução para nos ajudar neste quesito.

Comment: Rolou um outro tópico com esse assunto aqui mesmo no SOPT. [Dê uma olhada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257/como-proteger-o-c%C3%B3digo-fonte/7258#7258)

Comment: @emanuelsn, mas esse tópico que você postou, é apenas para JAVA, e no caso a pergunta é sobre ANDROID.

Comment: Vou apenas dizer isso pela enésima vez: ofuscação de código é que nem aquela alça que a gente tem no carro pro passageiro segurar quando o motorista acelera. Pode até dar uma sensação de segurança para quem não entende o que está se passando, mas não vai lhe proteger contra absolutamente nada.

Comment: Leia [como usar o proguard em projetos android](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Answer (score 2):

No próprio site oficial do Developer Android tem a solução.
O SDK vem com o **ProGuard**, que otmiza e ofusca o seu projeto android.

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Mas é como o usuário **Renan** citou, dá uma sensação de segurança, mas quem realmente entende de engenharia reversa, consegue driblar fácil.