# Como fazer engenharia reversa de um aplicativo android?

Tags: android, classes

Como a partir de um aplicativo android na extensão .apk, obter as classes, layouts, bibliotecas etc, ou seja, realizar a engenharia reversa?

Obs: utilizei o 7-zip como o Bacco aconselhou e resultou na seguinte pasta de arquivos:

[image: imagem]

As classes aparecem nessa extensão .dex e resources na extensão .arsc, pois acho que estão protegidas, como ter acesso as classes e resources desse aplicativo?

Comment: Você pode começar abrindo o .apk com _unzip_, _7-Zip_ ou ferramentas similares.

Comment: @Bacco postei a imagem dos arquivos gerados pelo 7-zip.. mas ainda fica protegida as classes e resources..

Comment: Relacionado: [Como proteger o código fonte?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/3117)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tem algumas ferramentas para isso:

- O **[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)** pode ser usado para descompactar o `.apk`;
- A **[dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/)** converte arquivos `.dex` em arquivos `.jar`;

  ```
  d2j-dex2jar.sh -f -o saida.jar entrada.apk  (linux)
  d2j-dex2jar.bat -f -o saida.jar entrada.apk (windows)
  ```
- A **[jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/)** serve para visualizar o conteúdo dos `jar`.

[image: jd-gui]

Comment: você sabe o motivo de alguns pacote que contem as classes não abrem atras do jd-gui.