# Como recuperar o projeto pelo executável?

Tags: android

Eu tenho um aplicativo em Android, só que eu perdi todo o meu projeto e ele e só esta instalado no meu celular funcionando corretamente, há algum jeito de eu recuperar todo o código só pelo executável que esta em meu celular? O meu projeto todo foi perdido e está funcionando corretamente em meu celular.

Obrigado pela Atenção.

Comment: Tem sim e já tem resposta veja: [Como fazer engenharia reversa de um aplicativo android?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34899/3635)

Comment: Tem sim dependendo, Você poderá fazer a recuperação por engenharia reversa como o nosso amigo Guilherme Nascimento postou, porem essa engenharia reversa só será possível caso você não tenha colocado nenhum tipo de proteção contra engenharia reversa quando fez o seu app.