# Como extrair imagens e sons e músicas no arquivo jar de qualquer jogos em java da Gameloft?

Tags: java, imagem, jar, engenharia-reversa

Eu tenho um jogo móvel no Formato JAR da Gameloft eu não posso ver onde estão as imagens e os sons e as músicas.

Eu só vejo alguns arquivos bin (ConditionExpr.bin e ResInfo.bin), alguns arquivos de classe (a.class, b.class, c.class, d.class, e.class, f.class, g.class, GloftSHFA.class, h.class, i.class, j.class, k.class, e alguns arquivos numerados de 0 a 999 chamados dataIGP FLSC.

Eu acho que as imagens e os sons e as músicas do jogo estão em quais dos arquivos? Como posso fazer para extraí-los?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer engenharia reversa de um aplicativo android?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34899/como-fazer-engenharia-reversa-de-um-aplicativo-android)

Comment: não é um aplicativo de android é um jogo em java da gameloft

Comment: Independente disso, tanto o android quanto o jogo da gameloft são feitos em java, e portanto você vai usar técnicas bem similares para fazer a engenharia reversa.

Answer (score 1):

O formato em que imagens, músicas e etc está gravado, é algo que fica a critério do desenvolvedor da aplicação. Geralmente, nada muito fora do padrão seria utilizado, mas alguns desenvolvedores poderiam ter razões para utilizar coisas bem fora do comum ou com várias camadas de criptografia e ofuscação para dificultar o processo de engenharia reversa.

Assim sendo, para iniciar o processo de engenharia reversa, comece descompilando o JAR. Para isso, seguem dois links de descompiladores Java modernos:

- https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon
- http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/

Comment: +1, mas se for essa a resposta, acho que é dup dessa aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34901/70 :)

Comment: @Bacco Concordo. É dup.

Comment: Mas vamos ver se é isso que ele quer antes :)