# Criptografar código fonte Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, criptografia, compilação, proteção

Preciso implantar um sistema pronto feito com o *framework* Ruby on Rails na empresa de um cliente, o problema é que esse cliente não pode ter acesso aos códigos-fonte.

Existe alguma maneira de "criptografar" ou "compilar" meu código para ficar ilegível para terceiros?

Comment: Por que você não provê só o serviço (servidor)? Daí ele não tem como ter acesso ao fonte.

Comment: O problema é que tem alguns clientes específicos que não podem depender da internet para o sistema funcionar, ou seja, preciso operar de forma offline. Eu preciso ter um servidor físico na empresa.

Comment: Tudo bem, e esse servidor não poderia ser seu, com contrato de manutenção, etc?

Comment: Temos uma pergunta semelhante, só que para Java. Acho que vale a pena conferir: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257/como-proteger-o-c%C3%B3digo-fonte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu falei nos meus comentários, acredito que seja melhor prover o serviço do que o programa em si. Até porque ofuscar o código não impede que sejam feitos processos de engenharia reversa e torne impossível o acesso ao código.
Dito isso, caso você opte mesmo por essa solução, é possível ofuscar o código, "compilando" ele com o [Ruby Encoder](http://www.rubyencoder.com/overview.html), por exemplo.

Outra alternativa seria fazer o código em outra linguagem (como C, por exemplo) e apenas usar a aplicação Ruby como um "wrapper" desse código. Esse ainda pode trazer outras vantagens, como ganho em desempenho, por exemplo.

Comment: Certo, vou fazer como o Felipe Avelar comentou na pergunta e o @Renan passou uma situação semelhante, vou criar um contrato de manutenção e um contrato de proteção do código fonte,a final, não posso evitar que façam Engenharia Reversa mesmo com o código criptografado. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 0):

Cara apesar de nunca ter procurado algo do tipo, tenta utilizar JRuby que pode ser compilado e executar em cima da VM do Java e integra-lo com o Rails através do Jetty-Rails. 
https://github.com/fabiokung/jetty-rails

Comment: Mas isso não deixa minha aplicação muito lenta?

Comment: Tem que testar cara, sinceramente nunca fiz uma aplicação jruby/rails rodar no jetty, porém em aplicações java ele é muito leve o guj roda em cima dele. Vale a pena testar pra ver.