# Protegendo Código Fonte ( Criptografar .jar )

Tags: java, jar

Tenho uma aplicação e gostaria de proteger meu código fonte, qual a maneira mais segura e correta a se usar ??

Comment: Talvez responda a sua pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257/como-proteger-o-c%C3%B3digo-fonte?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada no [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). Ele é um otimizador, ofuscador e "compressor" de arquivos class. Ele torna o processo de engenharia reversa do seu software em Java bem mais difícil. Ele é excelente, no que diz respeito ao que promete e é bastante eficiente. Pra você ter uma ideia, o próprio Android recomenda o ProGuard no desenvolvimento de aplicativos.