# É possível fazer engenharia reversa em softwares desenvolvidos em C++?

Tags: c++

É possível obter o código de um executável desenvolvido em C++? Entre Win32 Application e Windows Form Application, quais deles podem ser descompilados?

Comment: Eu acredito que seja possível sim, porque não seria? a não ser que o *software* a ser analisado esteja utilizando um [ofuscador de código](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29), um [compressor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression), por exemplo o Aspack, UPX, etc.

Comment: E mesmo assim, existem técnicas para desfazer o ofuscamento, compressão.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, me ajudou muito.

Comment: Se o AP tive-se perguntado, como proteger meu executável contra engenharia reversa, o comentário do @qmechanik poderia ser um começo de uma resposta :)

Comment: Eu perguntei isso por que eu gostaria de usar uma linguagem segura em que não fosse possível a descompilação. Qual linguagem eu deveria usar?

Comment: Não se preocupe com isso. Se preocupe em seu código ser bom. Ficar preocupado com isso as vezes vai o impedir de utilizar uma boa linguagem de programação. Para você ter uma linguagem que ninguém mais descompilasse você teria que desenvolver o próprio hardware, o proprio SO e depois a propria linguagem + compilador. E ainda teria que manter seu computador com cadeado e com usuários burros utilizando com tempo cronometrado, ainda correndo o risco de ser invadido. E no fim só para descobrir que as vezes o maior perigo é o que o pŕoprio programador faz.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como proteger o código fonte?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/3117)

Comment: @RafaelBluhm seu comentário poderia ser uma resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, como é possível de fazer em **todos** os tipos de código. Ora, se o computador pode lê-lo, assim pode o humano. Os maiores problemas (em relação àquele que descompila) são que alguns programas tem outros os vigiando (ex.: anti-hacks de jogos) ou (como disse o @qmechanik) que o programa foi ofuscado/comprimido. De qualquer maneira, pode se dizer que é impossível fazer um código totalmente seguro contra crackers e, assim, o programador deve se focar mais no qualidade do código.