# Se eu chamar um ficheiro de JavaScript esse código fica visível no browser (navegador)?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu sei que quando escrevo código diretamente em páginas HTML o JavaScript é mostrado mas e se eu chamar apenas o ficheiro, por exemplo, assim

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

O código será mostrado?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, não há nada que possa fazer para impedir isto. Faça o teste.

Se quer proteger um pouco, só um pouco, só contra leigos, não por questão de segurança, pode usar uma linguagem que gere WebAssembly.

Comment: Como consigo proteger o código do script para não ser copiado?

Comment: então e se ajax é javascript o ajax tambem ser'a visivel?

Comment: JavaScript será visível, AJAX é só uma forma de usar JS. A afirmação não faz sentido. Não é possível proteger o código, no máximo dificultar, mas aí já é outra pergunta e já foi respondida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/101

Comment: Esquece isso de proteger, é perda de tempo.

Answer (score 2):

Olá @AmadeuAntunes ele nao será mostrado no código, mas quem conseguir ver o diretório (link) onde se encontra o ficheiro, conseguirá visualizar o código.