# Como proteger uma Assembly de descompilação?

Tags: .net, segurança, criptografia, descompilação, .net-assembly

Hoje em dia existem muitos desmontadores e recompiladores para .NET Framework, o cara vai lá, faz um aplicativo e todos que tem um descompilador (por exemplo o IL Spy) pode ir lá, selecionar o Assembly e ver todo o código fonte do aplicativo, inclusive suas variáveis, que é o maior problema. Minhas questões são:

- **Posso proteger meu aplicativo contra descompilação?** Para que dê erro, ou de alguma criptografia ao tentar descompilar meu aplicativo em um descompilador?
- **Como protejo meus literais e variáveis?** Por exemplo, faço um aplicativo que usa requisições FTP para baixar um arquivo, ai tem a variável `servidor`, `username` e `password`, o cara que descompilou o aplicativo pode ter acesso ao conteúdo dessas três variáveis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de mais nada leia isso: [Como proteger o código fonte?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/101)

## Proteger a propriedade intelectual

Realmente há um certo exagero em achar que as pessoas vão descompilar e reaproveitar o código. Não é tão simples assim e tem que ser bem maluco pra fazer isto. Não vejo acontecendo por aí. Em códigos simples não vale o trabalho, em códigos complexos descompilar não resolve muita coisa.

Não é tão verdade que dá para recuperar o código original integral. Além de não recuperar os comentários, não recupera o nome das variáveis locais que também não deixa de ser documentadora. Sem essas coisas complica bastante o entendimento do código. Além disso o fluxo não volta exatamente como era. Na maioria das vezes conseguirá compilá-lo de novo mas será bem difícil dar manutenção.

Nenhuma técnica é eficaz, algumas dificultam um pouco. A ofuscação é o que dá melhor resultado porque ele modifica o código para ficar mais ilegível ainda e dificultar a vida dos descompiladores, mas ela não impossibilita a descompilação, não tem como fazer isto.

Se ainda vai fazer isto, use um dos [ofuscadores disponíveis para .NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET). Pela experiência quase todos os programadores sabem que raramente vale o trabalho.

Alguns deles fazem um trabalho "tão bom" que impede o *assembly* de funcionar corretamente. Outros geram enorme ineficiência de execução.

## Proteger dados sensíveis

Obviamente que não se deve colocar informação sensível dentro do código (senhas, endereços e outras informações que deveriam ser privadas). Isto deve ficar fora e deve ser criptografado (preferencialmente nem deveria estar junto da aplicação, dentro ou fora).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu usei o IDA e consegui sim ver o nome das variáveis e ver os comentários do programa.

Comment: É impossível ver o que não existe.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com isso?

Comment: Exatamente o que está escrito, se não tem comentários e os nomes das variáveis locais no executável nada poderá mostrar isso para você. O descompilador vai colocar alguma coisa que ele escolheu apenas.

Comment: Sei que não foi nem o sentido da pergunta nem o da resposta, mas tem um livro bem interessante sobre isso: [Java Secreto](https://www.docsity.com/pt/java-secreto-completo/4899528/). Trata, justamente, sobre técnicas de engenharia reversa e ofuscamento de código Java

Answer (score 3):

A melhor maneira de proteger seu código é OFUSCANDO.

Aqui possui uma [Lista de Ofuscadores para .NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET).

> Ofuscação é o processo de modificação de um assembly de modo que já
>   não seja mais útil para um hacker, mas continua sendo utilizável para
>   execução de suas operações. Embora possa alterar
>   os metadados ou as instruções método real, isso não altera o fluxo
>   lógico ou a saída do programa. Existem várias técnicas que podem ser
>   usados os quais são descritos abaixo.