# É possível editar e re-compilar revertendo o código-fonte?

Tags: engenharia-reversa

Para fins de exemplo, supondo que eu pegue um ROM de Atari, se eu aplicar engenharia reversa nesse ROM eu teria como fazer edições (mudar uma cor ou alterar um texto) e gerar uma ROM válida somente com as informações contidas nesse ROM?

Eu já tive que usar um descompilador para recuperar um código-fonte perdido de uma aplicação minha em Java, mas para recompilar eu utilizei o próprio compilador do Java, mas neste caso a pergunta é se eu teria, além de descompilar, criar um compilador somente com base no programa compilado.

Aproveitando, existem muita diferença entre emular uma ROM e descompilar uma?

Comment: ROM - Ready Only Memory ...."Read Only"

Comment: Poxa Magic, o fato de ser somente leitura não inválida a pergunta.

Comment: Não respondi "além de descompilar, criar um compilador somente com base no programa compilado" porque essa frase não faz muito sentido.

Comment: Mas pq vc acha que eu invalidei sua pergunta ? Só para vc saber eu dei +1 na sua pergunta... pq achei boa, e que não merecia o -1 que alguém deu...

Comment: Valeu Magic! :)

Comment: @bigown o que eu queria saber é se o "compilado" tem informação suficiente para que seja criado um re-compilador.
Supondo o exemplo de um tradutor de ROM, onde eu tenha a palavra `you` e queira trocar por `voce` que não caberá no lugar da frase original. Não consigo pensar em quanta informação eu precisaria para realocar ponteiros e criar um novo arquivo com a tradução no lugar da frase original.

Comment: Não existe re-compilador. Alterar só os textos costuma ser mais fácil è possí que que tenha que alterar todas referências dele porque os tamanhos são diferentes, mas é bem tranquilo. Não precisa saber quase nada sobre o código para alterar só o texto. Claro que depende um pouco como foi feito. Pode ter algumas coisas feitas de propósito para dificultar.

Comment: Sobre "Não existe re-compilador", supondo que eu gere um .java de um .class, altere esse .java e queira converter em .class novamente, mas sem usar o compilador "original".

Comment: @MarcusBecker e o que usaria no lugar do "compilador original"?

Comment: O programa que gerou o código fonte inicialmente.

Comment: @MarcusBecker novamente isso não faz o menor sentido.

Comment: Desculpa, não sei explicar. Deixa eu tentar uma última vez. Encontrei um programa prog.k, eu sei que esse programa foi gerado por um compilador que não existe mais, muito antigo, mas eu adoro esse programa e gostaria de criar programas similares. Ele roda através de uma VM que ainda existe. Eu consigo reverter todo binário em código-fonte? (Sim, você já respondeu). Eu conseguirei fazer qualquer alteração nesse fonte ou estarei limitado a gerar a mesma saída, sempre gerando o mesmo número de bytes do prog.k inicial?

Comment: @MarcusBecker Se você obtém o fonte, você faz o que bem entender com ele, é um código como outro qualquer, provavelmente menos legível, mas faz o que quiser. Em termos abstratos, genéricos, é isto, concretamente se você vai conseguir ou não nesse caso é outra estória.

Comment: Eu acho que vou estar atado às funções encontradas no source. Por exemplo, eu descompilo uma função `draw`, eu posso criar um editor para gerar essa função e conseguir gerar uma nova versão do jogo, chamando `draw` quantas vezes eu quiser. Em outras palavras, se eu não tivesse mais Ataris na Terra e encontrasse uma única fita e descompilasse o código dela eu estaria fadado a somente recriar as instruções encontradas naquela fita.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, é possível modificar qualquer código. Claro que em ROM terá que gerar uma nova, já que ela não permite escrita.

É possível descompilar virtualmente qualquer código, mas alguns são bem difíceis. Precisa ter muita informação que nem sempre está disponível. Em geral engenharia reversa é feita em cima do Assembly mesmo, que é possível obter fácil em 100% das situações.

Claro que nenhum código descompilado será tão legível quanto ao original. em muitos casos nem perto..

Algumas linguagens usam um *bytecode* intermediário padrão e rico em informações, então é possível recriar o código original de forma muito próxima. Em geral haverá pequenas mudanças da forma original do algoritmo, mas fazendo a mesma coisa, o estilo obviamente será do descompilador, não terão comentários e costuma perder os nomes de variáveis locais.

Java, C# e qualquer linguagem que não costuma gerar um binário nativo são assim. Note que [C# pode gerar código nativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101).

Não tem nada que possa fazer para impedir. O que dá para fazer é dificultar, criar situações que o descompilador se complique, que mude nomes significativos para coisas ilegíveis. Mas os [ofuscadores podem causar problemas de execução no código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/117519/101).

Emular uma ROM tem nada a ver com descompilar uma. Não é necessário descompilar para emulá-la.

Talvez esteja havendo alguma confusão do que é um compilador. Há uma pergunta que fala disto: [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). E outra que fala como ele funciona: [Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).