# Vale a pena criptografar banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, criptografia

Recentemente eu venho tendo a curiosidade sobre a utilidade de se criptografar todos os campos de todas as tabelas de um banco de dados.

A ideia é a seguinte:

1. Criar dois secrets (um no banco e outro na aplicação);
2. A aplicação fica responsável por criptografar/descriptografar os dados;
3. Todos os dados que vão pro banco já estão criptografados;
4. A aplicação usa os dois secrets (dela e do banco) para criptografar/descriptografar os dados.

As vantagens que eu vejo são:

> - Qualquer forma de extração de dados pontuais que não seja pela aplicação resulta em dados criptografados, e portanto inúteis para o invasor.
> - Mesmo no caso de uma cópia completa do banco, o invasor teria apenas os dados criptografados, sem utilidade.
> - O invasor obteria sucesso apenas no caso de uma invasão em ambos os servidores: Servidor de BD e Servidor com código da aplicação.

Vale a pena trabalhar com esse nível de segurança para evitar vazamentos em larga escala no caso de invasões?

Comment: Você precisa avaliar o desempenho da aplicação para criptografar/descriptografar os dados, ou você não irá levar isso em conta?

Comment: Por que criptografar um dado que é público? Por exemplo, o nome de um usuário ou produto

Comment: @Costamilam é público até certo ponto. Se você somar o nome do usuário a outras informações também "inofensívas", em um vazamento com milhões de contas, você tem ensumos para campanhas de phishing, spam, engenharia social, etc.

Comment: Mas a diferença é entre pegar esses dados invadindo seu banco (que é bem dificil) e fazer um parse dos dados providos pela sua aplicação (bem mais fácil)

Comment: Escolta armada para caminhão de mudança ,  o preço da operação não paga o roubo , tem de pesar quanto custaria a perda do dado , uns anos atrás a Petrobrás teria perdido um computador com dados de reservas de petróleo , o dado valeria bilhões de vezes o preço da máquina , quanto vale seu dado ?

Comment: @Motta estou partindo da premissa de que o dado seja altamente valioso e sensível.

Comment: Realmente não trabalho com dados criptografados , nem sei o impacto mas acredito que o dado precisaria ser muito sensível para fazer uso de criptografia , mas mesmo criptografado a questão cai em um ponto fraco , um usuário com aceso a informação extraí o dado sigiloso e a vende , queria até alguma bibliografia sobre isto.

Comment: Diria que hoje em dia não mais,  pois os padrões de seguranças estão  abstraidos em varias camadas, mas  se  você estiver  por exemplo  utlizando  uma tecnologia  mais velha,  ai  talvez valeria a pena, mas sabendo  que qualquer processo  entre criptografar firá com  que sua aplicação sofra com perda de desempenho.

Answer (score 3):

Essa não é uma resposta que se dá para um cenário global, porque muita coisa influencia na decisão a ser tomada, entre elas:

- O grau de confidencialidade das informações armazenadas no banco;
- <s>O desempenho da máquina por parte do banco;</s>
- O desempenho da máquina por parte do cliente;
- O tamanho das informações armazenadas e das consultas a serem realizadas.

A principal ideia de encriptar o conteúdo de um banco de dados é proteger seu conteúdo. O princípio da criptografia é proteger que alguém não entenda/leia/intercepte o que dois pontos compartilham. De qualquer forma, é possível interceptar informações antes delas serem encriptadas, ou após serem descriptografadas.

Até mesmo, é possível interceptar a chave compartilhada, uma vez que você mencionou uma transação simétrica, onde a ponta A e a ponta B compartilham a mesma chave privada.

> - Qualquer forma de extração de dados pontuais que não seja pela aplicação resulta em dados criptografados, e portanto inúteis para o invasor.

Se ele conseguiu extrair informação do seu banco sem uma legítima "autorização", seu banco é inseguro e há falhas de segurança nele. Proteger o conteúdo dele faz com que você espere *exploits* e vazamentos do mesmo. Portanto, um dos motivos da proteção de informação interna é a **ciência da autenticação insegura.**

> - Mesmo no caso de uma cópia completa do banco, o invasor teria apenas os dados criptografados, sem utilidade.

Complementando o que disse acima, se ele conseguiu invadir o seu banco, ele vai conseguir invadir sua aplicação, e logo a chave privada. Muitas vezes, as técnicas de invasão de bancos podem ser globais e não destinadas aos bancos, como por exemplo, ele pode ter acessado o servidor onde o banco está hospedado. Logo, ele terá a chave simétrica. Mas não faz nenhum sentido ter a chave privada armazenada no servidor destino.

> - O invasor obteria sucesso apenas no caso de uma invasão em ambos os servidores: Servidor de BD e Servidor com código da aplicação.

Na verdade, se ele invadisse o cliente, ele já conseguiria acesso tanto no banco de dados e nem precisaria do código da aplicação. As transações entre o cliente e os demais servidores poderiam ser interceptadas em um ambiente destinado. Por mais que o pacote venha criptografado de sua origem, ele deve ser descriptografado em seu cliente, e brevemente, armazenado em sua memória aquela informação.

Você pode encriptar a sua transação com outra ponta usando [SSL/TLS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), onde seu nome já explica o que está ocorrendo ali. A proteção é dividida numa chave assimétrica entre as duas pontas. O [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) faz isso bem, e também otimiza a entrega dessa transação.

Se você quiser proteger o disco onde seu banco está armazenado, você pode utilizar [EFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker). Também é recomendado utilizar um certificado de autenticação **SSH** para acessar o servidor onde suas informações estão armazenadas. Utilizar uma simples senha para acessar um servidor onde há tanta informação confidencial não faz nenhum sentido.

No [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_encryption) há um artigo explicando exatamente esse assunto, é bom para complementar o que você leu aqui.

Em suma, criptografar seu banco de dados não irá prevenir uma exposição de dados. Talvez um pouco, mas não o suficiente. A proteção deve ser investida em autenticação e segurança pelas transações, e claro, no seu cliente. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260014/como-fazer-upload-de-maneira-segura?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C6.0709) é bem explicado como você protege seu cliente com uploads seguros, e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117519/como-proteger-uma-assembly-de-descompila%C3%A7%C3%A3o) mostra como proteger uma string, no seu caso, uma chave simétrica.