# Criptografia para código de plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, criptografia, plugin-wordpress

Terminei um plugin para wordpress e não quero deixar o código aberto. Já tentei usar um simples ofuscador, mas depois de ofuscar o wordpress não reconhece como plugin.

Alguém tem uma luz de como proteger o meu código?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como proteger o código fonte?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257/como-proteger-o-c%c3%b3digo-fonte)

Comment: Uma dica: ofuscar código-fonte altera nomes de métodos e variáveis, coisas que o Wordpress confia que vão estar corretos. O que você precisa fazer é simplesmente configurar o ofuscador para não mexer em nada que faça referência ou estenda as APIs do Wordpress. Cale notar que um ofuscador dificulta que outras pessoas mexam no seu código, mas não impede totalmente que elas façam modificações ou mesmo usem sem a devida licença.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, se você quer um plugin protegido, acho viável criar um plugin premium e validar a licença a cada nova instalação

No entanto, acredito que se seu plugin é importante para os demais usuarios, porque não liberar o acesso para toda a comunidade, assim,  além de divulga-lo, ele também poderá ser melhorado.

Comment: A Validação dele é feita por e-mail! Sem a confirmação do e-mail de compra não tem como instala-lo. Mas, isso não protege o código do plugin.

Eu preciso proteger, esse plugin não vai ser aberto para a comunidade! É um plugin comercial.]

Comment: Se atente como é feita essa validação por e-mail. Se não é fácil monitorar o trafego de rede de retorno negativo e então criar um falso servidor retornando positivo. Imagine que exista um campo de e-mail e ao enviar para `meusite.com/verificar` é retornado `true` ou `false`. Então sempre que digita um e-mail "invalido" é retornado `false`. Basta que a pessoa redirecione o meusite.com para um outro IP (no Windows faz isso no hosts) e então nesse novo IP sempre retorna `true`. Pronto, a instalação será feita. PS: ISSO É APENAS EXEMPLO, para resumir tudo em um comentário.

Comment: É isso mesmo que eu faço, mas isso não me preocupa, se eu criptografar o código, ninguém vai saber como funciona a ativação!

Comment: @AndersonCosta Criptografar não adianta, pois antes de ser executado ele vai ter que ser decifrado (ou o computador também não vai conseguir interpretar o código!), o que significa que a chave de criptografia tem de ser enviada junto do código cifrado. E se a chave está lá, qualquer atacante pode decifrar...