# Quão protegido está meu código, com variáveis privadas?

Tags: python, independente-de-linguagem, private

```
class Conta(object):
    def __init__(self, numero_conta, nome_titular='anonimo'):
        self.__nome_titular = nome_titular
        self.__numero_conta = numero_conta
        self.__saldo = 0.00

    def getNomeTitular(self):
        return self.__nome_titular

    def setNomeTitular(self, nome_titular):
        self.__nome_titular = nome_titular
```

O que eu gostaria de saber exatamente é quão protegido está meu código quando uso variaveis privadas e de quem estou privando minhas variáveis. 
Sei que privo uma variável para esta não seja modificada por outra classe, porém, minha dúvida em relação a usuários maliciosos, ou seja, estou me protegendo deles também?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como proteger o código fonte?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/3117)

Comment: Não, principalmente no Python, pois não existe esse encapsulamento na linguagem, a única coisa que ele faz é renomear as propriedades iniciadas em `__*` para `_Classname__*`. Ou seja, ainda seria possível alterá-las de fora da classe com `obj._Conta__saldo = 999999`. Veja [aqui](https://repl.it/GQBX/0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Este não é um mecanismo de segurança, muito menos um mecanismo que sirva para usuários. O mecanismo é apenas para facilitar um pouco a programação.

O que ele faz é exatamente o que foi descrito na pergunta, ele não deixa a variável privada ser acessada de outras partes do código que não seja esta mesma classe, nada mais que isso.

Na verdade é até pior, essa proteção ocorrer em condições normais, se forçar o acesso em um nível mais baixo não tem proteção alguma.

A única coisa que ocorrer é um código normal dar erro se tentar acessar essa variável de fora desta classe, como se ela não existisse, mas existe e tem como subverter isso. É como um sinal vermelho, se você quiser passar, você passa.

Python fornece bem pouca proteção para código. Se sua aplicação precisa disto para funcionar bem, ela está errada.

Answer (score 5):

No paradigma de **orientação à objetos**, existe o que é denominado **encapsulamento** de propriedades e métodos. É bastante comum encontrar materiais em que é dito que a função do encapsulamento é proteger os dados de um objeto, que de certa forma é verdade, porém não no sentido de manter inacessível quando externo à classe. O encapsulamento serve para você definir regras de negócio que se aplicam às suas propriedades quando feito a interface com o mundo externo.

É comum em linguagens de programação definir três níveis de encapsulamento: *public*, *protected* e *private*. Quando definido como *public*, nenhuma regra de negócio é exigida à propriedade, por isso permite-se que a mesma seja definida diretamente quando externo à classe. Quando definido *protected*, as regras de negócio se aplicarão apenas quando o valor vier do meio externo à classe, mas classes derivadas da mesma possuem liberdade para definir novos valores diretamente. Quando definido como *private*, apenas a própria classe tem liberdade de definir valores diretamente; de qualquer outra origem as regras de negócio se aplicarão.

As regras de negócio são aplicadas às propriedades através dos métodos *getter/setter*.

> Para os exemplos abaixo, foi considerada uma linguagem de programação hipotética, de tipagem dinâmica. Os nomes da classe, métodos e propriedades foram gerados aleatoriamente e não possuem relação direta com a lógica apresentada.

Considerando a definição abaixo de uma classe com três propriedades, cada qual com seu nível de encapsulamento:

```
class Foo:

    private meeten
    protected festal
    public tamera
```

Sendo que as propriedades *protected* e *private* possuem obrigatoriamente regras de negócios, é definido os métodos *getter/setter* para cada:

```
class Foo:

    private meeten
    protected festal
    public tamera

    public getMeeten ():
        ...

    public setMeeten (value):
        ...

    public getFestal ():
        ...

    public setFestal (value):
        ...
```

Sendo os métodos supracitados responsáveis pela interface das propriedades com o meio externo, é de suma importância que os mesmos sejam definidos com encapsulamento *public*.

Considera-se agora algumas regras de negócio para a aplicação:

- `meeten` deve ser do tipo `string` com no máximo 255 caracteres;
- `festal` deve ser do tipo `int` com valor entre 0 e 255;

A implementação destas regras seria algo semelhante à:

```
    public setMeeten (value):

        if (type(value) != "string"):
            throws TypeError;
        else if (len(value) > 255):
            throws InvalidArgumentException;

        this.meeten = value

    public setFestal (value):

        if (type(value) != "int"):
            throws TypeError;
        else if not (0 <= value <= 255):
            throws InvalidArgumentException;

        this.festal = value
```

Com isso já é possível entender a proteção que o encapsulamento gera. Definidas as regras de negócio, pode-se considerar que a aplicação não funcionará quando as mesmas não forem válidas. Por exemplo, se a propriedade `meeten` for um valor inteiro. Utilizando a classe acima, tentando atribuir um inteiro à `meeten`:

```
inst = Foo()
inst.setMeeten(1)
```

Uma exceção do tipo `TypeError` seria disparada. Esta é a proteção que o encapsulamento define. Como a aplicação não funcionaria corretamente quando `meeten` for do tipo inteiro, ela obriga o valor passar pelo método `setter` onde são validadas as regras de negócio. Se inválidas, o fluxo de execução do programa é alterado pela exceção, impedindo a execução errônea da aplicação.

O mesmo acontece com a propriedade *protected*, porém, considera-se que em classes derivadas, a aplicação "saiba o que está fazendo", então é dada a liberdade à mesma de alterar diretamente o valor da propriedade. Por exemplo:

```
class Bar extend Foo:
    public cheetah ():
        this.festal = 10
```

É permitido à classe `Bar` acessar diretamente a propriedade `this.festal`, porém, perceba que se um valor for atribuído à propriedade que não validem as regras de negócio, por exemplo atribuir uma `string` à `festal` que deveria ser do tipo `int`:

```
this.festal = "anything"
```

Não será disparado nenhuma exceção e a aplicação poderá executar normalmente, provavelmente gerando um resultado inesperado. Nestes casos, é recomendado, mesmo que possua a liberdade de acessar a propriedade diretamente, fazer o uso do método `setter` de modo a centralizar todas as regras de negócio em apenas um lugar do código.

As propriedades do tipo *public* geralmente são assim definidas quando não existem regras de negócio, em que a aplicação funcionaria de forma esperada para qualquer tipo de entrada.

Óbviamente que detalhes desse funcionamento podem variar conforme a linguagem considerada. Por exemplo, em C++, se uma propriedade é definida como *private* ou *protected* e é tentado acessá-la diretamente no meio externo à classe, um erro será disparado. Já em Python esse encapsulamento não existe. No máximo, o Python remapeia as propriedades e métodos iniciados com `__*` para `_Classname__*`, assim uma propriedade chamada `__foo` na classe `Bar` seria remapeada para `_Bar__foo`, mas o acesso direto a este último é liberado, pondendo acessar do meio externo `Bar._Bar__foo = 0` sem ocorrer erros. Isso ocorre porque no Python é considerado que o desenvolvedor tenha conhecimento do que está fazendo, então lhe é dada toda esta liberdade. Em C++ (e acredito que Java), já é um pouco mais rígido, obrigando o uso dos métodos `getter/setter`. No Python, iniciar o nome da propriedade com `__` é basicamente para dizer ao devenvolvedor depois: "Ei, talvez não seja uma boa acessar isto diretamente. Faça isso apenas se realmente souber o que está fazendo.". Em C++ seria "Não faça isso!".

Resumindo, o encapsulamento apenas cria uma proteção para que sua aplicação funcione como deveria, definindo as "portas de entrada" da classe. De maneira alguma ela protege seu código de um usuário acessá-lo, se o mesmo possuir acesso ao seu servidor e códigos fonte. Para isso, você pode ler mais sobre em [Como proteger o código fonte?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257), como citado nos comentários.