# Deveríamos utilizar todas variáveis como privadas?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação

- Deveríamos sempre utilizar os atributos de uma classe como privados?
- O que as variáveis privadas ajudam a prevenir?
- Como você decide se uma determinada propriedade deve ser privada ou não? CASO, por padrão, cada campo FOR privado, então por que há membros de dados públicos em uma classe?
- Em que circunstâncias uma variável deve ser tornada pública?

Pesquisando na internet, são encontrados inúmeros "tutoriais", falando como é definido um atributo do tipo ***private***, mas  não dá um escopo de uso do atributo, quando você deve usar um e não outro.

A melhor definição que eu encontrei foi no próprio [SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-modificadores-public-default-protected-e-private):

> **Private**:
>   A única classe que tem acesso ao atributo é a própria classe que o define, ou seja, se uma classe `Pessoa` declara um atributo privado chamado `nome`, somente a classe `Pessoa` terá acesso a ele.

Comment: Eu fiz [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189172/5878) sobre encapsulamento abordando mais o lado de aplicação de regras de negócio aos atributos, talvez lhe é útil em algo.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

O que você costuma ler são as chamadas boas práticas. A pessoa diz o que você deve fazer sem dizer porque, muitas vezes porque a pessoa nem sabe o porquê. É comum inclusive a pessoa estar só repetindo o que ela "aprendeu" sem questionar o porquê daquilo.

> Deveríamos sempre utilizar os atributos de uma classe como privados?

Eu acho que não, tem gente que acha que sim. Depende de uma série de circunstâncias e da linguagem que está usando, sem falar na filosofia que você adotou.

> O que as variáveis privadas ajudam a prevenir?

Previne que outras classes acessem aquela variável de forma direta, como você já sabe.

> Como você decide se uma determinada propriedade deve ser privada ou não? CASO, por padrão, cada campo FOR privado, então por que há membros de dados públicos em uma classe?

Cada um tem um critério. Algumas pessoas decidem que todas serão privadas. Algumas decidem tornar públicas só as que precisam do máximo de performance. Outras escolhem tornar pública todas as variáveis que só acessam o seu valor de forma simples sem precisar de processamento. Outras analisam o domínio como um todo para tomar uma decisão.

Novamente tudo isso depende da linguagem que está usando, da tecnologia acessória que pode exigir uma determinada forma, da filosofia adotada, dos requisitos de manutenção, a forma como a classe será consumida, só para citar os principais.

Cada uma tem implicações de manutenção se um dia precisar mudar. Tudo que é público faz parte da API, mudar isso pode ser traumático. Mas depende. Se você tem controle total sobre a aplicação isso não é tão difícil assim se tiver as ferramentas certas.

Tem casos que você quer que a variável realmente seja só um detalhe de implementação, aí tem que ser privada, tudo que é público faz parte do contrato que você precisa espeitar em grande parte das situações, mas não todas como algumas pessoas acham. Precisa ser pragmático.

> Em que circunstâncias uma variável deve ser tornada pública?

Sempre que achar que a privada não é adequada, dentro dos parâmetros já passados acima.

Tem uma [pergunta com mais informações e *links* importantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134750/101) para se aprofundar sobre o assunto.

## Complemento após edição da pergunta

Agora que foi tirada a [independente-de-linguagem](/questions/tagged/independente-de-linguagem) e colocada a *tag* de [php](/questions/tagged/php) eu diria que não tem necessidade usar variáveis privadas, pelo menos se tiver um [*getter* e *setter*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) que fazem nada além de retornar o valor ou atribuir o valor passado. Lembre-se que *PHP* é uma linguagem de *scripts*.

Tem quem ache que, mesmo em linguagem de *script* deve-se adotar técnicas usadas em linguagens *enterprise*.

Por outro lado, o ganho de usar a variável pública é bem pequeno em *PHP*. As variáveis de classes em *PHP* são a mesma coisa, não há otimizações. Ainda assim eu prefiro não colocar linhas de código que eu nem sei se serão úteis.

Note que é usar os métodos mágicos é diferente de usar métodos `getXXX()` e `setXXX()` já que assim terá que mudar o código dos consumidores se precisar incluir algum processamento no acesso a estas variáveis. Mas reforço que se está fazendo um *script*, isso é tranquilo. Você está usando PHP para fazer *scripts*, certo?

Claro que se a variável genuinamente só deve ser acessada pela classe, se não está criando um encapsulamento artificial, aí o uso da variável privada é interessante.

Variáveis privadas ajudam [obter a coesão e evitam o acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96656/101) não intencional.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).