# Qual a diferença entre var e private var?

Tags: c#

Qual a diferença entre

```
private string s;
```

e

```
string s;
```

?

Tem alguma diferença entre os dois exemplos ou é só a forma de escrever?

Comment: Relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189162/101