# Criptografia Cliente / Servidor / Arquivo / Ofuscador

Tags: java, criptografia

Olá,

Estou criando um Jogo em Java usando o LibGdx, porém quero saber algumas coisas.

- Qual é a melhor criptografia para comunicação entre Cliente / Servidor (para ninguém interceptar o pacote que eu envio)
- Qual é a melhor criptografia para Arquivos (Para ninguém extrair os modelos do jogo, texturas etc)
- Uma dúvida bem difícil de ser resolvida: Qual é o melhor ofuscador? (bem, se eu colocar a private.key no meu jogo, o hacker pode extrair ela, e o código fonte também) (existe alguma coisa que protege 100% o código + os arquivos?)
- Qual é o melhor programa que passa um arquivo .jar para .exe?

Comment: Relacionado: ["Como proteger o código fonte?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7257/215) Não tenho muito a dizer quanto a ofuscadores e proteção de arquivos disponibilizados para o usuário, além do que já escrevi na pergunta linkada, mas quanto à comunicação eu sugiro simplesmente usar um canal TLS/SSL (ex.: https em vez de http, wss em vez de ws, etc). O *overhead* por pacote costuma ser pequeno, aliás tão pequeno quanto possível de garantir confidencialidade, integridade e autenticidade (pois não basta garantir que ninguém vai ler seus pacotes, também é preciso impedir de alguém alterá-los).

Answer (score 0):

A criptografia simetrica tem melhor performance na comunicação cliente servidor.

Para converter um arquivo jar em exe podes usar: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Denis,

Em quanto ao melhor ofuscador, sabe um melhor?

Comment: Faz tempo que não uso, mas esse link é uma boa referência: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Bytecode_obfuscation