# Sobre a criptografia RSA

Tags: segurança, criptografia

Olá,

A criptografia RSA gera a public.key e a private.key

Porém, se eu fizer alguma aplicação em java, e o "hacker" pegar essas keys, ele pode extrair o conteúdo.

Dá para camuflar essas public.key e private.key que ficarão dentro da aplicação?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como proteger o código fonte?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257/como-proteger-o-c%c3%b3digo-fonte)

Answer (score 3):

A criptografia basicamente funciona assim:

- (a) Aquilo que é escrito utilizando-se a chave privada só pode ser lido com a chave pública.
- (b) Aquilo que é escrito utilizando-se a chave pública só pode ser lido com a chave privada.

A ideia é que a sua chave pública você compartilhe, enquanto que a chave privada deve ser guardada e protegida de todas as formas possíveis. **Se a sua chave privada vazar, toda a garantia de proteção da criptografia será perdida.**

O algoritmo RSA (ou qualquer outro de chave assimétrica) parte do pressuposto de que a sua chave privada é segura. Não faz parte do algoritmo e criptografia dizer como ou o que você faz para guardar essa chave privada, ele apenas utiliza a chave que você dá para ele. O algoritmo de geração de chaves também não diz como você deve proteger suas chaves, ele apenas as produz e te entrega.

O caso (b) acima é usado para quando alguém quer escrever uma mensagem criptografada que apenas você pode ler. Uma vez que ela é criada com a sua chave pública, então qualquer um poderá escrevê-la, afinal a chave é pública. Entretanto, apenas você, que tem a posse da chave privada, poderá ler.

O caso (a) acima é usado para assinatura digital. Se você publicar uma mensagem criptografada com a sua chave privada, todos poderão ler utilizando a chave pública. Entretanto, a sua autoria será garantida e confirmada, pois a única forma de essa mensagem ser legível com a sua chave pública é se ela tiver sido gerada com a sua chave privada que só você tem acesso. Isso serve para garantir a autenticidade de informações.

Se o hacker tiver acesso a sua chave privada, ele poderá tomar o controle da sua criptografia, ler as suas mensagens particulares e também se passar por você. É mais ou menos o mesmo que acontece quando algum hacker tiver acesso a sua senha.

Se você estiver tentado a distribuir a sua chave privada dentro da aplicação, você provavelmente está fazendo errado, pois você nunca deve distribuir a sua chave privada.

Se o propósito da aplicação for enviar alguma mensagem para um servidor central controlado por você, ela só precisará da chave pública utilizada pelo servidor. A chave privada deverá estar bem protegida e bem guardada dentro do servidor e nunca sair de lá.

Se a aplicação também precisar dar autenticidade as mensagens geradas por ela e certificar a identificação do autor, você pode gerar um par de chaves públicas e privadas diferentes para cada instalação do aplicativo (dentro do próprio aplicativo) e enviar a chave pública para você ou para terceiros. Cada aplicativo deve manter a guarda da sua própria chave privada da melhor forma possível. E novamente, você nunca deve colocar a chave privada do servidor dentro da aplicação.

Dentro da aplicação, a proteção da chave privada pode ser feita por qualquer meio que ofereça um mínimo de segurança, tal como colocar em algum arquivo interno. Entretanto, você não precisa se matar para deixar essa chave privada do aplicativo ultra-segura porque cada instalação usará uma chave privada diferente. Assim sendo, se um hacker conseguir obter a chave privada usada no aplicativo instalado na instalação X, apenas a instalação X estará comprometida, e não todas as instalações e nem o servidor. Desta forma, o seu cuidado será apenas para garantir que o aplicativo não vaze a respectiva chave privada.

Answer (score 2):

A criptografia RSA **utiliza** (não gera) um par de chaves, uma chave pública que pode ser conhecida por todos e uma **chave privada que deve ser mantida em sigilo**. Justamente por isso que se chama privada.
Toda mensagem cifrada usando uma chave pública só pode ser decifrada usando a respectiva chave privada.

Mais detalhes sobre o algoritmo RSA na [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA).

Comment: Bom, OK, mais e criptografia de arquivos? O Cliente precisa da private.key para extrair os arquivos. Tem outro método que proteja a private.key?

Comment: Talvez isso te ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257/como-proteger-o-c%C3%B3digo-fonte
Eu não me preocuparia se fosse uma aplicação compilada gerando um .exe (diferente de Java e os class)

Comment: Tá, e se eu passasse uma aplicação .jar para .exe tem algum problema? (usando isso http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: O link que mencionei tem boas repostas sobre isso.

Comment: Nenhum software é aprova de engenharia reversa, esqueça isto, nenhum, nem mesmo se utilizar os _tamper-resistant_, como Denuvo. Sempre será possível usar um IDA para obter o Assembly. >:D